# Question on regex not performing as expected

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to change the suffixes of companies such that they are all in a common pattern such as Limited, Limiteed all to LTD.

Here is my code:

```
re.sub(r"\s+?(CORPORATION|CORPORATE|CORPORATIO|CORPORATTION|CORPORATIF|CORPORATI|CORPORA|CORPORATN)", r" CORP", 'ABC CORPORATN')
```

I'm trying `'ABC CORPORATN'` and it's not converting it to `CORP`. I can't see what the issue is. Any help would be great.

Edit: I have tried the other endings that I included in the regex and they all work except for corporatin (that I mentioned above)

Comment: You could add a word boundary at the end `|CORPORATN)\b` https://regex101.com/r/NeAsZY/1 and perhaps shorten it to `\bCORPORA(?:T?TION|TE|TIO?|TION|TIF|TN)?\b` See https://regex101.com/r/eW7js8/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that all te patterns begins with `"CORPARA"`, so we can just go:

```
import re
print(re.sub("CORPORA\w+", "CORP", 'ABC CORPORATN'))
```

Output:

```
ABC CORP
```

Same for the possible patterns of limited; if they all begin with `"Limit"`, you can

```
import re
print(re.sub("Limit\w+", "LTD", 'Shoe Shop Limited.'))
```

Output:

```
Shoe Shop LTD.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This simplifies everything and more readable too! Appreciate the help! :)